# Regex expression to find parse bottle size from string (e.g. 750ML)

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have a long list of strings that are different products in my database, each with a product label and product sizes (including packaging size) of the product. I would like to split the strings into two substrings: the first part up until the size and the second part, which contains the size of the liquid and possibly the size of the packaging.
I have the following strings for example:

```
str1 = 'PRODUCTA 1909 SUPERIOR GIN 89 PROOF 750ML' 

str2 = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 1.5L 2PK' 

str3 = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 1.5L 6PK' 

str4 = 'PRODUCTC FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 50ML 5PK'
```

What I would like to get is:

```
str1a = 'PRODUCTA 1909 SUPERIOR GIN 89 PROOF' 
str1b = '750ML'

str2a = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP'
str2b = '1.5L 2PK' 

str2a = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP'
str2b = '1.5L 6PK' 

str4a = 'PRODUCTC FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP' 
str4b = '50ML 5PK'
```

The difficulty here is that a lot of products have digits in the product label (e.g. 1909 in string1) and that some product sizes are not only the amount of liters (1.5L, 750ML, etc.), but also the package size it comes in (2pack, 6pack, etc.).

I would like to split every numerical digit before the letter 'L' , and ignore dots. Then, ML or CL or L would be treated identically and 1.5L should still be captured as 1.5L and not 15L.

Can someone help me with the correct regex expressions to do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Update, `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[µMK]?L(\s*[0-9]+PK)?)` or if python supports PCRE... `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[µMK]?L(?:\s*\d+PK)?)` these are making some presumptions though. Also assumes `µMK` are the only prefixes for volumes

Comment: Would you ever encounter `0.5L`? Would it be written as `.5L`?

Comment: Not an answer but `ML` means `MegaLiter`, `milliLiter` is `mL`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a regex pattern and an example of how you can achieve your task:

PS: Thanks to @Toto for his comment about pipes

```
import re


def get_volume(text):
    # You can add all the list of volume fractions
    _volume = re.search(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?[MCDNPF]?L(\s+\d+PK)?)', text)
    if _volume:
        volume = _volume.groups()[0]
        return text.replace(volume, '').strip(), volume
    return text, None


str1 = 'PRODUCTA 1909 SUPERIOR GIN 89 PROOF 750ML'
str2 = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 1.5L 2PK'
str3 = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 1.5L 6PK'
str4 = 'PRODUCTC FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 50ML 5PK'

texts = [str1, str2, str3, str4]

for elm in texts:
    print(get_volume(elm))
```

Output:

```
('PRODUCTA 1909 SUPERIOR GIN 89 PROOF ', '750ML')
('RODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VA', '1.5L 2PK')
('RODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VA', '1.5L 6PK')
('RODUCTC FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VA', '50ML 5PK')
```

**Update:**

If you need to handle the case of `.5ML` use this pattern:

`r'((\d+(\.\d+)?|(\.\d+))[MCDNPF]?L(\s+\d+PK)?)'`

So, for example:

```
str1 = 'PRODUCTA 1909 SUPERIOR GIN 89 PROOF 750ML'
str2 = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP .5L 2PK'
str3 = 'PRODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VAP 1.5L 6PK'
```

It will return:

```
('PRODUCTA 1909 SUPERIOR GIN 89 PROOF ', '750ML')
('RODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VA', '.5L 2PK')
('RODUCTB FLAV GIN 70 PROOF VA', '1.5L 6PK')
```

Comment: No needs for pipes in a character class, `[M|C|D|N|P|F]` must be written `[MCDNPF]` or it will match pipes.